# I can't figure out why my React site doesn't render when using react-context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to implement React Context feature, but for some reason I can't seem to successfully render the page. When I launch the site it just stays blank. Even though it compiles without any errors.

I have an App.js where the main code is written :

```
import './App.css';
import { UserProvider, useUser } from "./UserContext";

const LoggedInUser = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  return (
    <p>
      Hello <span className="Username">{user.name}</span>
    </p>
  );
};

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <h2>Blog App</h2>
      <LoggedInUser />
    </header>
  );
};

const Page = () => {
  const { user } = useUser();
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>What is Lorem ipsum?</h2>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
      </p>
      <p>Written by {user.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>hello</h1>
      <Header />
      <Page />
    </div>
  );
}

function Root() {
  return (
    <UserProvider>
      <App />
    </UserProvider>
  );
}

export default Root;
```

Then the UserContext.js file:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext(undefined);

export const UserProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user] = useState({
    name: "John",
    email: "john@example.com",
    dob: "01/01/2000"
  })
  return <UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}></UserContext.Provider>
}

export const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

And lastly index.js file, which may or may not be relevant to this issue:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

If I use `export default App` instead of `export default Root` and comment `<Header />` and `<Page />` components in the App's return the page displays hello. But if I leave `export default Root` and comment `<Header />` and `<Page />` the hello text header disappears.

Comment: Use the children inside `UserProvider`: `<UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't pass the `children` in UserContext. The code should be corrected as:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const UserContext = createContext(undefined);

export const UserProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [user] = useState({
    name: "John",
    email: "john@example.com",
    dob: "01/01/2000"
  })
  return <UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
}

export const useUser = () => useContext(UserContext);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your user provider isn’t rendering its children prop.

Include the children prop between your UserContext.Provider tags.

Comment: Thank you, I figured that by adding `{children}` inside `return <UserContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>` fixed the problem!